# MySQL Sorting grouped records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

This is my table containing the log:

```
message                  | data
----------------------------------------------
ttt,tu10=UP,tu20=UP      | 2016-11-11 10:15:05
ttt,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 10:13:05
ttt,oper=UP,oper2=UP     | 2016-11-11 10:13:01
ttt,oper=DOWN,oper2=DOWN | 2016-11-11 10:07:05
hhh,tu10=UP,tu20=UP      | 2016-11-11 10:05:04
hhh,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 10:05:01
hhh,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 09:43:01
hhh,tu10=UP,tu20=UP      | 2016-11-11 09:37:04
hhh,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 09:35:05
ttt,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 09:35:01
ttt,tu10=UP,tu20=UP      | 2016-11-11 09:33:05
ttt,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN  | 2016-11-11 05:35:01
hhh,tu10=UP,tu20=UP      | 2016-11-11 05:33:05
```

I created this query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *,COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM log
        WHERE data > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
        GROUP BY substring_index(message,',',1)
    ) AS tmp
WHERE count > 3
```

Prints on the screen: 'message', 'data', 'count'

Gets something like:

```
ttt,tu10=UP,tu20=UP     | 2016-11-11 09:33:05 | 6
hhh,tu10=DOWN,tu20=DOWN | 2016-11-11 09:35:05 | 5
```

And I would like to get the first one, something like:

```
ttt,tu10=UP,tu20=UP | 2016-11-11 10:15:05 | 6
hhh,tu10=UP,tu20=UP | 2016-11-11 10:05:04 | 5
```

I have tried several ways to sort but I gave up.

Comment: U didn't mention what do you want in your question... in addition to your expected result, please say what do you want concerning this result.

Comment: "GROUP BY substring_index(message,',',1)" This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: I want to display a message, the date and the number of appearances, but I would like to view the latest message and date.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick for this purpose:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(message ORDER BY data DESC SEPARATOR '|'), '|', 1) as message,
       MAX(data) as data, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM log l
WHERE data > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
GROUP BY substring_index(message, ',', 1)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Do note that `GROUP_CONCAT()` has an internal limit set by a system variable, with a default value of 1,024.  It will generate an error if the messages exceed that length.  You can reset the length.

An alternative is:

```
select l.*
from (select substring_index(message, ',', 1) as m1, max(data) as maxd
      from log
      group by substring_index(message, ',', 1)
      having count(*) >= 3
     ) ll join
     l
     on ll.m1 = substring_index(l.message, ',', 1) and ll.maxd = l.data
```